# JS Confirm box misbehaving in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, confirm

I wrote a little program to demonstrate the DO WHILE loop for students. It draws a line using `<hr />` then asks for confirmation to repeat the action. Here it is:

```
function drawline()
{
var draw = true;
do 
{
    document.getElementById("lineArea").innerHTML += "<hr />";
    draw = confirm("Draw another line?"); // clicking "Yes" in a confirm box stores "true" in the variable 'draw'.
}
while (draw)    //  This is equivalent to "while (draw == true)"

document.getElementById("lineArea").innerHTML += "No more lines";

}
```

The problem is that it works fine in FF and IE but not in Chrome Version 57.0.2987.110. In Chrome, no lines appear until the user presses "cancel" in the confirm box, then the number of lines appears depending on how many times "OK" was pressed prior to that. 
And, when I step through the code in Chrome's developer tools, it works as expected!
Any ideas what's happening here? I know the confirm box often frowned upon, but I want to keep the code simple for my students.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```js
function drawLine() {
document.getElementById("lineArea").innerHTML += "<hr />";
}
```

```html
<a id="addline" onclick="drawLine()">add line</a>
<div id="lineArea"></div>
```

Comment: oh i see it was about the do while... anyway i think you can not easily change how and when chrome validates confirm boxes